# Linq orderby culture (danish, æøå)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm having a problem with my orderby linq expression. It generates the output in a wrong order. I'm from Denmark and creating a danish website, therefor the order has to be exact ofc.

Here is my query:

```
var model = (from w in db.News
                orderby w.Title
                select w).ToList();
```

The output is:

```
1, 123
2, æøå
3, hallo
4, know
```

The correct order should be like this:

```
1, 123
2, hallo
3, know
4, æøå
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: If the ordering is really done at the database, what is the collation of the SQL server? It should be Danish or Danish-Norwegian in your case, I guess.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass string comparer to `OrderBy` method if you will use fluent Linq syntax:

```
var model = db.News.OrderBy(w => w.Title, StringComparer.InvariantCulture)
              .ToList();
```

BTW you can create string comparer specific to your culture with `StringComparer.Create` method:

```
StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("da-DK"), true)
```

Comment: Hey and thanks. This is however cause an error. Saying: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable........ method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: @KasperHyldalPedersen unfortunately Linq to Entities does not support ordering with customer comparer, because it cannot translate it to SQL. I suggest you to move ordering to client side with adding `AsEnumerable()` call: `db.News.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(...)`

Comment: Aha, alright the AsEnumerable() part did the trick. Thanks for your help, I could have been up all night due to this problem :) Can't thank you enough.

Comment: @KasperHyldalPedersen It is however natural to choose a Danish or Danish-Norwegian collation on the database. In that case the database should do `order by` the way you want, and you don'y have to do the operation client-side.

Comment: Aha I see, as for now I'm just working with the SqlServer Compact.. So when I in the future expand to a hosted database (proberly danish) this could get fixed?

Comment: @KasperHyldalPedersen (Tag my name when you comment on a comment (as opposed to question or answer) by me.) I can's see why you can't set the collation on SQL Server Compact. See [Working with Collations (SQL Server Compact)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835498.aspx). You can use either `Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS` (case insensitive) or `Danish_Norwegian_CS_AS` (case sensitive).