# LINQ Skip and limit with ordering causes odd results

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, entity-framework-core

I am usig LINQ to query a database for profiles. It uses Skip and Limit and Ordering to load profiles in order but not all at once.

```
  return (
    queryable
        .OrderBy(usr => usr.FirstName)
        .ThenBy(usr => usr.LastName)
        .Skip(skip)
        .Take(limit)
        .Include(usr => usr.Workplaces)
        .ThenInclude(uwp => uwp.Workplace)
        .Include(usr => usr.ProfilePicture)
    );
```

Now I have started to run into some issues regarding ordering. Lets say I first skip 0 and limit by 20. This should give me 20 profiles ordered by firstname and then lastname. It has some odd behavior when people have the same lastname. Lets say this was retrieved:

```
0.firstname: A  lastname: a
1.firstname: A  lastname: b
...
19.firstname: P lastname: Å
```

Then When i skip 20 and limit by 10. I get the following result:

```
20.firstname: P  lastname: A
21.firstname: Q  lastname: A
```

Record 19 and 20 are now in the wrong positions! 'A' comes before 'Å'. What am I missing here? My take is that lastname ordering did not work properly as record 20 should have been returned first instead of 19. I have made sure that my culture is set correctly to swedish by using CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name. I have also tried setting the culture in the compare with the suggestions here: [Linq orderby culture (danish, æøå)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994098/linq-orderby-culture-danish-%C3%A6%C3%B8%C3%A5) it only crashes at runtime.

Comment: Hi @Nisse32! Have you tried to trim your data? Is be possible that there is a space before 'X'?

Comment: I don't understand the data results here, can you expand to include a full set and describe what is incorrect?

Comment: I updated the question. I'm beginning to think it has to do with culture. Record 19 lastname is the Swedish Å. Maybe C# thinks its actually A which indeed comes before X.

Comment: @Nisse32, So now is there any problem remaining with ordering?

Comment: Yes, I tried suggestions found here:´https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424481/linq-orderby-on-generic-list-returns-not-entirely-alphabetical-list but they don't work, the application crashes on runtime with the error "This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.OrderBy' is currently not supported.". Is it maybe because I'm using IQueryable?

Comment: And my culture is alread set in the startup class to swedish so it should already be using that. I have also checked the value of CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name; and it is swedish. Doesn't that mean that ordering on strings should include Swedish characters?

Comment: It's not the C# culture but the database collation that determines the sort order. Your modified code makes it likely that the database collation orders 'Å' before 'A' (was unthinkable with the original example, 'X').

Comment: The comments on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15994118/5389131) to the question you have linked mention that `IQueryable` does not support ordering using a custom comparer. They also point out that you could configure your database so the ordering fits your needs, as @GertArnold mentions here as well.

Comment: Does the problem also occur if you explicitly add the correct StringComparer to your `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`? If that is the case, what is the return of mySwedishStringComparer.Compare("A", "Å"). Is that what you expected? And what if you only create a list of strings and sort? Does it get the correct order?

Comment: I'm still thinking it might be something else.. Now antoher person registerd themselves. I have 1. Firstname A, Lastname T and 2. Firstname A, Lastname Ö and number 1 came first, so it was sorted correctly...

Comment: My DB Collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. However I just ran a query using SSMS, ordering on firstname and then lastname and it gives the same incorrect order as my code in the question. As I'm using skip and limit, Å is retrieved first and then sorted, so yeah I probably have to configure the database. Problem is, I can't change collation without dropping the entire db and recreating it...